# lubridate parses dates one day off

Tags: r, lubridate

When I put a single date to be parsed, it parses accurately

```
> ymd("20011001")
[1] "2001-10-01 UTC"
```

But when I try to create a vector of dates they all come out one day off:

```
> b=c(ymd("20111001"),ymd("20101001"),ymd("20091001"),ymd("20081001"),ymd("20071001"),ymd("20061001"),ymd("20051001"),ymd("20041001"),ymd("20031001"),ymd("20021001"),ymd("20011001"))
> b
 [1] "2011-09-30 19:00:00 CDT" "2010-09-30 19:00:00 CDT" "2009-09-30 19:00:00 CDT"
 [4] "2008-09-30 19:00:00 CDT" "2007-09-30 19:00:00 CDT" "2006-09-30 19:00:00 CDT"
 [7] "2005-09-30 19:00:00 CDT" "2004-09-30 19:00:00 CDT" "2003-09-30 19:00:00 CDT"
[10] "2002-09-30 19:00:00 CDT" "2001-09-30 19:00:00 CDT"
```

how can I fix this???  Many thanks.

Comment: Note time zone mismatch (UTC to CDT).  I think you're getting dates that are equivalent to midnight UTC but are 3 hours "earlier"  (although I'm a little confused because CDT is UTC-5 hours, not UTC-3 hours).  Please post the locale info from your `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: @BenBolker It is 5 hours in his example: 19 == 24 - 5.

Comment: @BenBolker Weird: `.POSIXct(unlist(lapply(list(x,y),unclass)),tz = "UTC")` (from `c.POSIXct`), where `x` and `y` are two of their dates.

Comment: (My point being that I would have thought that `c.POSIXct` would preserve the time zone attributes, despite the general rule of `c` dropping attributes.)

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't claim to understand exactly what's going on here, but the proximal problem is that `c()` strips attributes, so using `c()` on a POSIX[c?]t vector <strike>changes it from UTC to the time zone specified by your locale</strike> strips the time zone attribute, messing it up (even if you set the time zone to agree with the one specified by your locale).  On my system:

```
library(lubridate)
(y1 <- ymd("20011001"))
## [1] "2001-10-01 UTC"
(y2 <- ymd("20011002"))
c(y1,y2)
## now in EDT (and a day earlier/4 hours before UTC):
## [1] "2001-09-30 20:00:00 EDT" "2001-10-01 20:00:00 EDT"
(y12 <- ymd(c("20011001","20011002")))
## [1] "2001-10-01 UTC" "2001-10-02 UTC"
c(y12)
## back in EDT
## [1] "2001-09-30 20:00:00 EDT" "2001-10-01 20:00:00 EDT"
```

You can set the time zone explicitly ...

```
y3 <- ymd("20011001",tz="EDT")
## [1] "2001-10-01 EDT"
```

But `c()` is still problematic.

```
(y3c <- c(y3))
## [1] "2001-09-30 20:00:00 EDT"
```

So two solutions are

- convert a character vector rather than combining the objects after converting them one by one or
- restore the `tzone` attribute after combining.

For example:

```
 attr(y3c,"tzone") <- attr(y3,"tzone")
```

@Joran points out that this is almost certainly a general property of applying `c()` to `POSIX[c?]t` objects, not specifically `lubridate`-related.  I hope someone will chime in and explain whether this is a well-known design decision/infelicity/misfeature.

**Update**: there is some discussion of this [on R-help in 2012](https://mailman.stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-July/317759.html), and Brian Ripley comments:

> But in any case, the documentation (?c.POSIXct) is clear:
>
> ```
>   Using ‘c’ on ‘"POSIXlt"’ objects converts them to the current time
>   zone, and on ‘"POSIXct"’ objects drops any ‘"tzone"’ attributes
>   (even if they are all marked with the same time zone).
> ```
>
> So the recommended way is to add a "tzone" attribute if you know what 
>   you want it to be.  POSIXct objects are absolute times: the timezone 
>   merely affects how they are converted (including to character for
>   printing).

It might be nice if `lubridate` added a method to do this ...

Comment: I don't think you need to have created the date in lubridate for this to happen.

Comment: I think this is the same principle that leads to the result of  `c(factor("a"), factor("b"))`

Comment: If you use `list` instead of `c`, attributes are preserved. Combining mixed tz lists with `c` also preserves the information.